# porque salen los else todos juntos

Tags: c++, condiciones, else

hola estoy haciendo un pequeño juego para adivinar palabras pero cuando compilo la parte donde estan los if y else tiene como un bug cuando no se cumple la condicion if se ejecuta el else pero no solo el primer else sino que todos los que le sigan solo dejare esta parte del codigo porque lo demas no creo que sea el problema.
no hay error al compilar sino que muestre todos los else.

```cpp
if(strcmp(palabra,propulsor)==0){
        cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
        puntaje++;
        }
        else {cout<<"Su palabra no es correcta no obtiene nada :("<<endl;}
        fflush(stdin);
            if(strcmp(palabra,hola)==0){
            cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
            puntaje++;
            }
            else {cout<<"Su palabra no es correcta no obtiene nada :("<<endl;}
            fflush(stdin);
                if(strcmp(palabra,sistema)==0){
                cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
                puntaje++;
                }
                    if(strcmp(palabra,funcionamiento)==0){
                    cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
                    puntaje++;
                    }
                        if(strcmp(palabra,susi)==0){
                        cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
                        puntaje++;
                        }
```

[image: el problema]

Answer (score 1):

No es una respuesta, pero no podría ponerlo en el campo de comentario.
No se exactamente lo que quieres hacer, pero el código hace lo correcto según fue escrito. Recuerda que C/C++ anidan procedimientos dentro de las llaves. Y tus `if` o `if-else` solo tienen 1 (un) nivel de anidamiento, o sea, que el programa va a intentar ejecutarlos todos.

Este es el mismo código, sin modificarle nada, solo el estilo. Como verás, el programa siempre intentará ejecutar todos los `if`, y si cumple alguna condición, te la va a mostrar.

```
if(strcmp(palabra,propulsor)==0){ // Nivel1
    cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
    puntaje++;
} else {
    cout<<"Su palabra no es correcta no obtiene nada :("<<endl;
}
fflush(stdin);
if(strcmp(palabra,hola)==0){ // Nivel1
    cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
    puntaje++;
} else {
    cout<<"Su palabra no es correcta no obtiene nada :("<<endl;
}
fflush(stdin);
if(strcmp(palabra,sistema)==0){ // Nivel1
    cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
    puntaje++;
}
if(strcmp(palabra,funcionamiento)==0){ // Nivel1
    cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
    puntaje++;
}
if(strcmp(palabra,susi)==0){ // Nivel1
    cout<<"su palabra es correcta obtiene 1 punto :)"<<endl;
    puntaje++;
}
```

Para anidar `if` dentro de otras estructuras `if-else`, tienen que estar dentro de las llaves del `if` anterior, ejemplo

```
if(<condicion1>) { // Nivel1
    // Accion1
} else {
    if(<condicion2>) { // Nivel2
        // Accion2
    } else {
        if(<condicion3>) { // Nivel3
            //Accion3
        } else {
            //Accion4
        }
    }
}
```

En C++ se puede abreviar el uso anidado de condicionales con la estructura `else if`. El mismo código anterior se puede reescribir así

```
if(<condicion1>) { // Nivel1
    // Accion1
} else if (<condicion2>) { // Nivel2
    // Accion2
} else if(<condicion3>) { // Nivel3
    // Accion3
} else {
    // Accion4
}
```

Comment: osea que si escribo muchos if else uno debajo del otro se ejecutaran igual??
mi programa hace esto compara en la condicion de cada if la palabra ingresada por el usuario con la que ya esta cargada en la memoria si son iguales te da un punto pero si no entra el else y hay esta el problema se ejecutan todos los else no se que estare haciendo mal ya me fijare mejor quieres que ponga todo el codigo completo para que te guies mejor ?

Comment: creo que ya entendí probare el ultimo código que dejaste a ver si funciona.

Comment: no funciono tendre que preguntar mas